# How to call an api on every path/route change?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, routes

I wish to call an API on the path/route change of a react web app. How can I achieve this if I wish to call an API only once the route or the path changes.

Note that I have tried this in route file inside an useEffect by giving dependency of the route but it is executing for all the routes at once, eg. 50 routes, 50 API calls which is expected.

Is there anything with which help I can achieve this?

Comment: Can you past what you have so fare to make a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: @yousoumar I have a basic react app with around 50 routes, I wish to call an API once on every route change. I would be unable to reproduce this on codesandbox as I only like to know an approach to achieve this.

Comment: Have you tried lazy imports and suspense component

Comment: Not working, API is calling like 50 times as number of routes are 50.